# How to disable comment autocomplete of /// in C++ for Visual Studio?

Tags: autocomplete, comments, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I am writing C++ code in .cpp files. Until very recently (updating to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3), it used to be that typing /// would do exactly that. Now there is an autocompletion where the /// is replaced by something of the form:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model"></param>
```

I understand that this is trying to help in documenting functions, but I am not using automatic document generation. How do I disable my text being replaced?

I don't want to disable intellisense entirely, but I would like to disable any automatic replacement or augmentation of what I type that doesn't get my explicit approval by e.g. pressing tab. I have already disabled automatic brace completion and the C# XML documentation completion for ///.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the right behavior for xml document. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019).

To disable it, please enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Text Editor**-->**C#**-->**Advanced**

uncheck the option `Generate XML documentation comment for ///`

[image]

**Actually**, this option is a good feature, it will automatically generate a description structure based on the following method names and parameter types.

**Update 1**

For C++ projects, please enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Text Editor**-->**C/C++**-->**Code Style**-->**General**

select **Generated documentation comments style** to `None`.

[image]

Comment: I should have added that this is for C++ code in a .cpp file. I disabled the C# option as you suggested, and it is still generating XML documentation.

Comment: Sorry for that. The first suggestion is for c#. For c++ projects, you should check another option to disable xml documentation for `///`. I have updated my answer and please see `update 1`.

Comment: Thank you. It was my mistake for not being clear in the first place, and I know I am in a minority using C++ instead of C#. I updated my title and description after seeing your reply about the C# solution. I appreciate your help.